# Is it secure for PHP to access files above the document root?

Tags: php, security, mysqli

I have seen many questions like this but I have come across something which looks very simple and I’m wondering if it is secure.

As I understand it, my document root is a folder called `public_html` on my host (rochen). I am looking to implement a database for the first time and need to secure the user and password etc. From what I have read, this info needs to be outside of the document root.

One very simple example is to create an ini file at the same level as the `public_html` and use this line in my PHP to access it (assuming my php file is directly below `public_html`):

```
$config = parse_ini_file('../config.ini');
```

The dot dot thing I know from DOS is the old “up one level” trick.

The database would then use the ini file contents like so:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
```

My ini file with the sensitive information is above the document root and according to what I have read, is secure. This seems a much simpler way of achieving the result compared to many of the other answers I have read. Is this correct or do I have some massive security hole I am missing please?

Comment: The idea is if someone has access to the folder above your web root, they can already read the `../config.ini` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> One very simple example is to create an ini file at the same level as the public_html and use this line in my PHP to access it (assuming my php file is directly below `public_html`).

This thinking—in and of itself—won’t secure anything.

If any of your scripts need to read that file, that file is potentially at risk. So the key is not to come up with elaborate file system scheme store the configuration file, but rather understand how you can effectively block access to the file with a few simple steps.

For example, this is your configuration file:

```
$config = parse_ini_file('../config.ini');
```

And you are in PHP and worried about prying eyes, correct? Well if this is a custom PHP codebase and you are free to name the file whatever you want, then just make it an `.ini.php` file like this:

```
$config = parse_ini_file('../lembasts_config.ini.php');
```

The key idea being most hacking attempts come from malicious robots attempting to access commonly named files. So `config.ini` is something some script kiddie has already coded to look for. They don’t know what `lembasts_config.ini` let alone `lembasts_config.ini.php` is. So making the configuration name idiosyncratic to your needs will help “cloak” your config.

Then what is the `.php` version of `lembasts_config.ini.php` for exactly? Well its named PHP so you can something like this within the file itself:

```
;<?php
;die();
;/*

username="[your username]"
password="[your password]"
dbname="[your dbname]"

;*/

;?>
```

The idea is that `parse_ini_file` will parse the ini values as expected. But because of the `.php` extension, the `die();` will run if someone attempts to open it in a web browser.

The key to web security is simple: The vast majority of incursions come from automated scripts looking for common holes. Plug up the common holes with simple techniques like this and you make your codebase more secure.

Comment: Thanks - I'm very new to php but this is a great trick - putting ini values in a php script file! I guess it would be even better if my file was called kisjdn876wr8fkijnrfi.php?

Answer (score 0):

It's fine.
What *does* cause trouble is dynamic filenames that include "..", eg http://site.tld/page?param=value does a `include "..".$_GET['param'];`